# Unable to solve sql query having data in same table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a database and want to get this output. Someone asked me to do without using join and sub query but I am unable to do this by any method so can someone tell me in how many way we can get this output?

Table:

[image]

Output:

[image]

**Note:** My requirement is if someone pass in all subject then result should be pass else fail.

Comment: Most people here want formatted text instead of images.

Answer (score 3):

> I have a database and want to get this output. Someone asked me to do without using join and subquery

From your sample data and expected result you can use `where`

```
SELECT sid,res
FROM T
WHERE sub = 'E'
```

---

**EDIT**

> My requirement is if someone pass in all subject then result should be pass else fail.

If your requirement limit didn't use `where` you can use `MIN` with `group by`.

because `F` value samller than `P`.

**Schema (MySQL v5.6)**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `table1` (
  id int unsigned NOT NULL,
  sub varchar(6),
  rev varchar(6) 
) ;



INSERT INTO table1 VALUES
  (1,'E','P'),
  (1,'H','P'),
  (2,'E','F'),
  (2,'H','P'),
  (3,'E','P'),
  (3,'H','P');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT id,MIN(rev) 
FROM table1
GROUP BY id;

| id  | MIN(rev) |
| --- | -------- |
| 1   | P        |
| 2   | F        |
| 3   | P        |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/38xFeh6kQEsDEcz4Yw2c3N/0)

Comment: Really great out of box thinking :)

Comment: @D-Shih: You are trying to show only output but this is not correct way. What happend if I swap the res column value of sid 2?

Comment: @Hariom If there are some logic you could edit your question and explain more detail on it:)

Comment: Is there any reason votedown? the requirement was writed after my first answer.

Comment: @D-Shih: Also please edit your query from SELECT id,MIN(rev) 
FROM table1
GROUP BY id; to SELECT sid,MIN(res) 
FROM table1
GROUP BY sid;

Comment: @Hariom I think you need to tell us your question logic because your question only  `this by any method so can someone tell me in how many way we can get this output?`

Answer (score 2):

Use aggregation and group by

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f5d36431c8e62633cd73525cb7a6d366

```
select sid, min(res)
from tablename
group by sid
```

Comment: Hey one doubt can min function used for aggregation of characters?

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f5d36431c8e62633cd73525cb7a6d366 - check here

Answer (score 0):

To make it independent of the actual character values, we can first convert the P/F characters to numbers. Then we check the minimum and convert the result back to letters.

```
SELECT
    sid,
    (CASE WHEN MIN(CASE res
             WHEN 'P' THEN 1
             ELSE 0
             END) = 1 THEN 'P'
         ELSE 'F'
     END) AS res
FROM t
GROUP BY sid
```

Answer (score 0):

Requirement could be achieved by using JOIN. I am considering 'student' as a table name here

```
SELECT s.sid, 
       COALESCE(temp.res, 'F') AS res
FROM   student s 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT s1.sid, 
                         'P' AS res 
                  FROM   `student` s1 
                  WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT s2.sid 
                                     FROM   `student` s2 
                                     WHERE  res = 'F' 
                                            AND s1.sid = s2.sid)) AS temp 
              ON s.sid = temp.sid 
GROUP  BY s.sid
```

Comment: Hey Hariom, did you try this?

Comment: So please accept answer if it is work for you. Happy to help you

Comment: One of the requirements  without subquery and join